# Setting variable names with dimnames() in R

Tags: r, matrix

For plotting purposes (specifically for `vcd::mosaic()`) I want to set variable names (i.e. "temp" and "color" below -- what is the proper term??) for the rows and columns of a table or matrix, as one finds, for example in the built-in dataset `HairEyeColor`.  I am able to do so as follows:

```
x <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
dimnames(x) <- list(temp = c("hi", "low"), color = c("red", "blue"))
x
     color
temp  red blue
  hi    1    3
  low   2    4
```

My question is: if the row and column names are already set, is there a better way than this to add just the "temp" and "color" attributes?

```
names(attributes(x)$dimnames) <- c("temp", "color")
```

It seems awkward.

Comment: `names(dimnames(x)) = c("temp", "color")`

Comment: That works.  Am I correct that `names(dimnames())` can't be set for a data.frame?